# Malformed HTML causes Chat Ads to display incorrectly on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed

There appears to be some malformed HTML in Meta's sidebar that's causing the chat advertisements to be displayed incorrectly. The module which contains the "Frequently Asked" question list has a "linked" container inside of it, and either it or its parent module element appear to be missing a closing `</div>` tag.

This results in the subsequent modules (including the chat module) being what I believe to be unintentionally nested. As a result, the chat ads are shifted eight or so pixels to the right, causing part of them to be cut off. Note that this only happens on the main page, where the FAQ links are displayed.

The stripped-down version of the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="module" id="interesting-tags">
  <!-- Some very interesting tags -->
</div>

<div class="module">
  <h4>Frequently Asked</h4>
  <div class="linked">
  <!-- Some FAQuous links.. -->
  </div>

  <!-- There should be another closing tag here -->

  <div class="module" id="chat-feature">
  <!-- Some chatty stuff... -->
  </div>
```

I've opted to illustrate this tragedy with the following series of panels that compare MSO's sidebar to that of Gaming (complete with FHC and RCE (rchern-compatible emoticons)). The two right-most panels illustrate the shift which results from the nesting:

[image: Verified Genuine Situation-Specific Problem-Solving Thought Process Diagram™]

Comment: If it wasn't clear enough, the chat ad in MSO's home page can be reached like this: `div#sidebar div.module div.module#cheat-feature` -- the FAQ module only ends right before the feed link and the other modules are wrapped into it, resulting in excess padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I should have read your post *before* fixing this – that would have spared me from having to find the problem myself :)

Will be fixed next time we deploy, thanks!